# "NaN" when zooming and selecting by id

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm probably doing something wrong but the following fiddle is displaying some really strange behavior:

https://jsfiddle.net/pkerpedjiev/42w01t3e/8/

Before I explain it, here's the code:

```
function skiAreaElevationsPlot() {
  var width = 550;
  var height = 400;
  var margin = {
    'top': 30,
    'left': 30,
    'bottom': 30,
    'right': 40
  };

  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {
      // Select the svg element, if it exists.
      var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

      // Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
      var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");

      svg.attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

      var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .on("zoom", draw);

      data = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
        return data[key];
      }).sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.max_elev - a.max_elev;
      });

      svg.insert("rect", "g")
        .attr("class", "pane")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
        .call(zoom);

      var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) {
          return d.max_elev;
        }))])
        .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

      var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, data.length])
        .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

      var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) {
          return d.area;
        })))
        .range([10, 30]);

      zoom.x(xScale).scaleExtent([1, data.length / 30]);

      var gMain = gEnter.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      gMain.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom);

      function skiAreaMouseover(d) {
        gMain.select('#n-' + d.uid)
          .attr('visibility', 'visible');
      }

      function skiAreaMouseout(d) {
        gMain.select('#n-' + d.uid)
          .attr('visibility', 'visible');
      }

      // the rectangle showing each rect
      gMain.selectAll('.resort-rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .classed('resort-rect', true)
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr('id', function(d) {
          return 'n-' + d.uid;
        })
        .on('mouseover', skiAreaMouseover)
        .on('mouseout', skiAreaMouseout);

      var gYAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - margin.right) + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("right")
        .tickSize(-(width - margin.left - margin.right))
        .tickPadding(6);

      gYAxis.call(yAxis);

      draw();

      function draw() {
        function scaledX(d, i) {
         console.log('xd', d);
          return xScale(i);
        }

        function rectWidth(d, i) {
          return widthScale(d.area);
        }

        gMain.selectAll('.resort-rect')
          .attr('x', scaledX)
          .attr('y', function(d) {
           console.log('d', d);
            return yScale(d.max_elev);
          })
          .attr('width', 20)
          .attr('height', function(d) {
            console.log('d:', d)
            return yScale(d.min_elev) - yScale(d.max_elev);
          })
          .classed('resort-rect', true);
      }
    });
  }

  chart.width = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.height = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = _;
    return chart;
  };

  return chart;
}

var elevationsPlot = skiAreaElevationsPlot()
  .width(550)
  .height(300);

data = [{
  "min_elev": 46,
  "max_elev": 54,
  "uid": "9809641c-ab03-4dec-8d51-d387c7e4f114",
  "num_lifts": 1,
  "area": "0.00"
}, {
  "min_elev": 1354,
  "max_elev": 1475,
  "uid": "93eb6ade-8d78-4923-9806-c8522578843f",
  "num_lifts": 1,
  "area": "0.00"
}, {
  "min_elev": 2067,
  "max_elev": 2067,
  "uid": "214fdca9-ae62-473b-b463-0ba3c5755476",
  "num_lifts": 1,
  "area": "0.00"
}];

d3.select('#ski-area-elevations')
  .datum(data)
  .call(elevationsPlot)
```

So, when the page is first loaded, a rectangle will be visible in the middle. If you try scrolling on the graph, the `console.log` statements in the `draw` function will produce output. Notice that the `xd:` and `d:` statements all consist of just one object from the data set.

Now, if you mouseover the rectangle and try zooming again (using the scroll wheel). A bunch of `NaN` errors will be displayed. Now some of the `d:` and `xd:` statements will now print lists of objects.

Why is this happening? The underlying bound data never changed.

What puzzles me is that if these statements:

```
gMain.select('#n-' + d.uid)
```

Are changed to:

```
gMain.selectAll('#n-' + d.uid)
```

The fiddle behaves properly. Why does this make a difference? Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

For googleability, here's the error I get:

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to replace gMain.select/gMain.selectAll in the mouse event routines with d3.select(this)

The complicated solution seems to be that a single select binds a parents data to whatever is selected if you're acting on an existing selection. gMain is an existing selection and has the 3 data values as an array bound to it - console.log (gMain.datum()) to see - so when you do a gMain.select("#oneoftherects") you replace the single object in #oneoftherects with that array, thus knackering the x,y,width,height etc routines that expect one object. (Using d3.select doesn't do the same as d3 isn't a selection)

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#non-grouping

Comment: Thanks for the link! It's really helpful.