# d3 using different data in different update functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a very strange problem. I have a D3 tree layout where the nodes need to change their backgrounds and text when they're loading children via AJAX (when their state is set to 'loading').

This works fine for all nodes except the root node for some reason, because the root does change its text, but not its background. After setting the node's state to 'loading', the Chrome debugger shows this:

[image]

But then this:

[image]

Somehow, in the *same* update cycle, D3 has given the update functions two different values for the same variable. Also note that the dbId of the node (its unique ID) is the same in both cases, so it's not a different node.

How could D3 be passing old data to its update functions?

Full D3 code is [here](https://github.com/vqs318/Final/blob/master/src/index.js#L150) if that helps.

Comment: In `fetchData(node)` there are two calls to `this.render(node)`: the first call ([line 297](https://github.com/vqs318/Final/blob/master/src/index.js#L297)) happens after setting `node.state = 'loading'`, while the second one ([line 314](https://github.com/vqs318/Final/blob/master/src/index.js#L314)) occurs in the Ajax callback after setting the state back to `node.state = 'closed'`. Where is your break point? Are you sure, you are examining the same call to `render()`?

Comment: Positive. The ajax call takes several minutes (a very unoptimized database query), so it can't be the second render call

Comment: Well, they're different d values :-), so the change in the datum attached to the g element is either not getting propagated down to both the text and rect child elements or is being overridden somewhere else. Do you ever explicitly change the data value in a selection that picks out just the rect or the text element? Another thing, a single .select (not .selectAll) on an existing selection can copy the parent selection data to the selected element, there was an issue like that the other day : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864512/nan-when-zooming-and-selecting-by-id/

Comment: I don't believe I'm doing either. Very strange

Comment: In lines 268-286 in your code you have 3 .select statements, try changing them to .selectAll to see if that helps - it shouldn't do any harm at least

Comment: Actually yes, there is a line where I .select() something. Removing that made both functions have d.state = 'closed', not 'loading'. I don't understand why it's using a previous value. Could it be something to do with ID tracking? The nodes still have the same id as the last update cycle

Comment: Fantastic! I've worked it out thanks to your help. select() propgates the data downwards, which is actually what I *wanted* to do. Without it, the child elements weren't getting fresh data. https://github.com/vqs318/Final/blob/master/src/index.js#L291-L308 this works

Comment: Well, I wrongly thought the select's were causing the problem, not the way round it, but whatever works ;-)